# Water Heater not getting 240v?

Tags: electrical, water-heater, 240v

My water heater stopped working a few days ago and I've been trouble shooting it ever since.

I found water in the connection receptacle.  the leak from the the Air Conditioning unit above it has been addressed and fixed.  I disconnected the power, dried the receptacle, cleaned everything up, trimmed the wires, and made new connections to the water heater.

No results.

I purchased an electrical meter and after checking the wires connecting to the water heater, I'm only getting 106 - 107 volts.

I thought it was supposed to get 240v...is that not correct?

If so, what could be the culprit here?

---

Update 1:

I got the original readings from the wires coming into the water heater from the wall.  I'm including a photograph of this (this time it was reading 110v).[image]

---

Update 2:

I'm not sure what a "double pole" breaker is, so I'm attaching a photo of my breaker panel

[image]

---

Update 3:

This is the beaker for the water heater

[image]

---

Update 4:

Not sure if this helps, but when I connect the wires from the wall to the water heater and I check with the meter, I get a reading of "~ooo"  [I've wired the same way as before...I marked with tape which was connected to the 
black wire with tape since both wires from the wall are RED]

[image]

---

Update 5 (Jan. 4th):

I tested the power at the breaker panel (photo attached).

- I tested the top half by touching the BLACK Test Lead from the meter to the screw and the RED Test Lead to the ground wire.  Meter read 124V
- I tested the top half by touching the RED Test Lead from the meter to the screw and the BLACK Test Lead to the ground wire.  Meter read 124
- I tested the bottom half by touching the BLACK Test Lead from the meter to the screw and the RED Test Lead to the ground wire.  Meter read 124V
- I tested the bottom half by touching the RED Test Lead from the meter to the screw and the BLACK Test Lead to the ground wire.  Meter read 124
- I then tested the top half and the bottom half together (touching the RED Test Lead to the top and the BLACK Test Lead to the bottom) and the meter read 000. - I reversed the Test Leads (just in case) and also got 000.

I promptly replaced the cover to the breaker panel and escaped unscathed from this

[image]

[image]

---

UPDATE 6 (Jan. 6th):

Welp,

Not sure what is going on, but the water heater is working again.  I didn't do anything to it after the last test that I did on the breaker panel.

I guess my home realized I was fully committed to tearing it apart to solve this problem and decided to get it together to avoid further damage.

Not sure what to do, if there's anything to do.  I'm just glad I have hot water again.

Thank you to all who contributed and guided me through this interesting challenge.

Comment: You said "106-107 volts".  You didn't say where you measured this.  How about the voltage from RED to BLACK, RED to WHITE, and BLACK to WHITE?  If there is no WHITE, that would be good to know also.  A photo might help.

Comment: Also, you're measuring the voltage on the incoming wires?  Not at the thermostat or elements?

Comment: Measure it at the breaker too - unlikely to be a panel problem, but best to rule that out.

Comment: You state you cleaned things up so I guess you flipped the breaker off, was it a double pole ? Most water heaters are 240v but there are some that are 120v and as the other 2 comments ask we are looking to see that you have a 2 pole breaker, sometimes these are handle tied , or supposed to be, to pass inspection a home owner may have pulled a nail out (not legal but a way many single pole breakers were made into double pole)  many are 2 positions wide with a single handle. FYI the maximum voltage to ground should be close to 120v max but you will only see 240v hot to hot.

Comment: Did you turn the breaker back on when measuring. Also can you measure from hot1 to safety ground, and from hot2 to safety ground?

Comment: What's the reading between the black and red wires in the cable your photo shows?

Comment: Juan, welcome to the site. I've asked the community team to merge your accounts which will let you respond in comments and edits to your question. Note that posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: The breakers that don't have the GE logo and have a little metal piece connecting the two handles are double pole breakers.  Really, anything in that panel over 20A is double pole.  So which one controls the water heater?  Also, that looks like silver, and probably aluminum wire going to the water heater, so that connection requires special care/connectors.

Comment: It doesn't matter. All the 2-pole breakers are installed correctly.

Comment: Hi Juan,  first, you  can [edit] your question to add detail. Second, you're having problems doing that because you are using a "starter" account tied to a browser cookie, and either you're changing browsers/devices, or resetting your cookies.  Add an email address and password to your account, and that will stop happening.

Comment: You seem to have the edits well in hand!  Now, you see that flexible metal conduit, the one with the 2 red wires (don't worry about that) -- where is the other end of that flexible conduit?  Is it a junction box?  What is inside the junction box?  Continuous wire, or a splice?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica,  the other end of the flexible conduit goes into the wall.

Comment: @JuanZ. Under NEC it is illegal to "bury" junction boxes behind drywall or whatever.  Therefore that flexible conduit must go somewhere, and the 'somewhere' must be accessible. Does it go all the way back to the panel? Do you see two red aluminum wires there?  Or can you find any other junction box (may have other stuff in it) where it goes?  It may make an intermediate stop, and that may be where the problem is.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm assuming that the flexible conduit goes all the way to the breaker panel.  Not sure if there is a junction box in between, but I will check with the meter at the panel.  Not sure how to do that, but I will research that now.    Thank you, and I will post my finding shortly..

Comment: @JuanZ. shutting off that breaker shuts off both legs of the circuit, correct?

Comment: That's correct...

Comment: Is the breaker loose or wobbly in the vertical (up-down) direction at all? Have you tried cycling the handle from ON to OFF back to ON a few times and seeing if the circuit comes back to life afterwards?

Comment: Weird!! It's acting like the standard "idiot put their water heater on a duplex".  But that is NOT a duplex, that is a standard double-stuff 2-pole breaker in the GE Qline, and it is correctly placed.  Are you super sure  you measured between the two red wires, and didn't accidentally go upper red to brown or lower red to black?  Are any of your other 240V appliances malfunctioning?

Comment: Yeah, it's a half-with Qline 2 pole, and it's definitely correctly placed...indeed, is this the only 240V appliance that's been having trouble?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only appliance that's 240 that is acting up.  But like I update, it seems to be working properly now.